# First dropdown selection is not filtering second dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

I'm trying to filter dropdown based on selection of first dropdown, in my console log, everything is fine, but second dropdown allways showing all results, not filtered one, here is how I did it:

```
<!--Group-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">GROUP:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;"
            data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="articleGroups" required (change)="filterSubById(article.mainGroup.id)" [(ngModel)]="article.mainGroup">
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
      <option [ngValue]="group" *ngFor="let group of mainGroups">{{group.title}}</option>
    </select>
  </div> 
</div>

<!--Subgroup-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">SUBGROUP:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="subGroup" required [(ngModel)]="article.subGroup">
      <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
      <option [ngValue]="subgroup" *ngFor="let subgroup of subGroups">{{subgroup.title}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the outcome of the `filterBySubId` method back to the view. You're not doing anything with the returned value.

I'd do something like this:

```
filterSubById(Id) {
    this.filteredSubGroups = this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId == Id);
}
```

and in view

```
<option [ngValue]="subgroup"
        *ngFor="let subgroup of filteredSubGroups">{{subgroup.title}}</option>
```

Comment: well I said there in my post  `return this.subGroups.filter(item => item.parentId == Id);` isn't it the same?

Comment: hmmm? what do you think?

Comment: @billy_56, filter does not modify the original array, so you should keep a filteredsubgroups array which has the current filtered subgroups and an original subgroups array on which you apply the filtering

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: as @user700284 says. The filter did not modify the array, so the `subGroups` in template is still the same.

The `return` indeed returns the filtered value. But the value is not used anywhere. You'd need to write `(change)="subGroups = filterSubById(article.mainGroup.id)"` which is **not a good practice**.

Comment: @billy_56 If you edit your code as I suggest in my answer, it will work.

Comment: @user700284 your comment was more useful to me than the answer itself, so thanks a lot